# Two Headed Giant has two tags that need merging

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have [mtg-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-two-headed-giant) (x1 question) and [two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-headed-giant) (x16 questions). These tags both refer to the same two-on-two MTG format and we should merge them.

Is there a particular way around we should merge them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given all the other MTG tags are namedspaced into mtg-something, we should keep [mtg-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-two-headed-giant) as the primary tag and make [two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-headed-giant) a synonym. (And drop the synonym if an independent non-MTG game called "two-headed giant" comes along.)

Comment: Merge done. I tweaked the tag wiki while I was at it (the two had different descriptions).